# How to install Internet Explorer and/or Dissenter on Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, wine, arm64

I installed Ubuntu desktop 21.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4b. I want to switch from Mozilla Firefox, the default browser, to Internet Explorer and/or Dissenter. The only download I could find was an .exe and those are for Windows. I found that I need Wine, I've installed a 64 bit version of that, but the version of internet explorer I've tried only works on AMD64 processors, but what I have is an ARM64 processor.

Is there an emulator for ARM64 that is free and easy to configure? I could not find how to do it on a pi 4b at all.

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158832/how-to-install-the-dissenter-browser-on-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158832/how-to-install-the-dissenter-browser-on-ubuntu)

Comment: That does not work; I followed the instructions exactly. It says that my system is arm64 and it needs amd64.

Comment: @Peregrino69 There is no `dissenter-browser` in snaps, so the linked solution should not work for any architecture anymore. At least today.

Comment: @2-bituser Wasn't the Dissenter Browser discontinued? I cannot find an official download page. It used to be a Gab app, but there is no Dissenter Browser on their download page, other than a dead link to it.

Comment: Yeah. When I asked this, It was still downloadable. Wierd.

Comment: @2-bituser why would you want to use a discountinued browser IE? Also your title doesn't match your question...

Comment: Good idea. See my last edit

Comment: In case you are unaware, the MS Edge browser runs on my rasberry pi

Comment: Microsoft edge is not for me.

Comment: Hello, please don't edit your question so dramatically that existing answers become irrelevant. Peregrino69 has already provided an answer on your question about the Dissenter browser. The issue of installing Internet Explorer is completely different. Please post your question on Internet Explorer as a new question instead ("Ask Question" button) and roll back your edits to this question about the Dissenter browser. Or, at least, start that new question. If you do, please let @ArtemS.Tashkinov know, so that he can repost his answer to the IE question.

Comment: You are right about changing it drastically.  The thing is since Dissenter is dicontinued, I changed the browser I want.  I know internet explorer is dicontinued too, but at least I can download it.  (I fixed my problem by installing box86 and wine)

Comment: You still need a rollback. See "[Changing question etirely?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/812/423679)", "[Rolling back a completely changed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64459/837798)", "[Correct answer became incorrect after a question edit, what now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130995/837798)", "[What should I do when an edit would change the context of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148175/837798)".

Comment: Fair enough. (This question went off-topic so I has to change it)  I edied.  Both answers are now acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  I Tried an x86 emulator https://www.cnx-software.com/2020/11/19/box86-is-an-x86-emulator-for-raspberry-pi-and-other-32-bit-arm-platforms/ here's one.  This is what worked.  I installed it and then dissenter installed without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging. Dissenter browser is available only for the regular PC CPUs. Your system has an ARM CPU, and there's no download for that.

In your shoes I'd just bite the bullet and choose a different privacy-enhanced browser. There are many, Dissenter being the least well-known. Just google for `privacy browser arm64` and you'll find options. You might be able to install one just with standard `apt-get install` or Ubuntu's graphical package manager.

The only possibility at this point to get Dissenter running on your hardware is that to build it. The source code is available as a plugin for several browsers. Also Dissenter's core appears to be available, but that's a bit confusing as it's referring to Brave.

I'd suggest attempting building only once your skills have developed to the point where you can find stuff independently and know *how* to. Building from source leads to a rabbit hole affectionately known as [Dependency Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell), and without some real skill and know-how getting out of it is ... let's just say challenging. Speaking from experience.

Comment: I wouldn't say the "only possibility". qemu is of course another option to explore.

Comment: Is there a free emulator that can translate amd binaries into arm binaries??

Comment: @2-bituser Yes "qemu" can do it. Though the process of installing a deb (and its dependencies) for another architecture may be complex.

Comment: May I have the link(s) to download (and install) it?  If you put that in an answer form, (and if it works) you would have the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer has not been supported for ages now and I guess what you're really looking for is Microsoft Edge which has a native [AMD64 version for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). In order to run it under ARM64 you'll need to install qemu. More details are available [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=246886). Mind that even if Microsoft Edge runs and works it will be extremely slow.

There's a [32bit Wine](https://github.com/AlbrechtL/RPi-QEMU-x86-wine/blob/master/README.md) available for Raspberry Pi as well however I'm not sure it is the same uArch as yours. You can theoretically try running Internet Explorer 11.0 under it.

[Box64](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box64) can run Wine64 which allows to run a lot of x86-64 software on modern ARM devices.

Comment: I ran apt install wine32 but it said that it is not available but libwine may repalce it; I ran apt install libwine but it said "libwine had no installation candidate"   I already have a 64 bit wine installed; I said that in the question.

Comment: Wine alone will not work.

Comment: I have box64 which caused it to work. I also have used edge on other machines, and I hate it as it is very hard to uninstall.  On my dad's windows machine, It installed itself, and he can't uninstall it!  On the other hand, internet explorer is not like that at all.  I am NOT looking for edge.  Thank you anyway.